# ¿es posible usar git con xampp vm en mac?

Tags: php, xampp, macos

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en php en Mac, para eso tengo XAMPP VM pero quiero usar git para control de versiones, pero la ruta con la que quiero usar el git clone es algo confusa /nfs://192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/htdocs/comercial/

Alguien me puede orientar en esto?

(P.D.   Soy nuevo en esto)

Answer (score 1):

Solo abre una consola y dirigite a la carpeta que contiene tu proyecto y despues puedes dar git init para iniciar un repositorio luego de eso puedes trabajar con todos los comandos disponibles de git